# Within the parent class itself 'super()' is used, why?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am new to the programming in python and getting confused with the oops concept in python. I know `super()` is used to use the methods defined in the parent class, but I can't understand why the parent class itself using the `super()` keyword.

```
class BahdanauAttention(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units):
    super(BahdanauAttention, self).__init__()
    self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
    self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `BahdanauAttention` is inheriting from `tf.keras.Model`, meaning the `super` call within its `init` actually calls the `init` method of `tf.keras.Model`.

One more thing:
Since Python 3, you don't need to pass any arguments to the `super` call:

```py
super().__init__()
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read posts about `super()` method in Python 3, it 's tricky, especially with multiple inheritance (even if it's not the cas ehere), [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)